# Umbraco url's displaying home node in one node, sometimes

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

So I have an umbraco setup with a 'content' root node and then a 'home' node under that. Under the 'home' node is the content and the URLs are the name of those nodes for example I have a 'about u's node under home and it's URL is '/about-us/'

In the case of the 'news' node, below 'about us', its children some times get '/home/about-us/news/title' of the story as the URL, which throws a 404. I can see that this is the URL of the node on the properties tab, but if I republish it it returns to '/about-us/news/title' for a period before returning to the broken link.

I have only seen this behavior on this node, which contains new-item document types. I basically watched the umbraco tv video and created it following along.

It seems to be to be a umbraco bug, but I would really appreciate any help with the issue

Comment: Could you show the code you are using to generate the URL? Is it XSLT, umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id) ?

Comment: The listing is doing it's job, the problem is that umbraco thinks that the url is different as that is how it is displayed on the properties tab 'Link to document' section.

Comment: Seems it might be related to calls to umbraco.library:NiceUrlFullPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed obsidian's [link](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/22106-umbracoHideTopLevelNodeFromPath-not-working-(randomly)) in his answer and read about someone else having the same issue. It seems to be traces back to a `umbraco.library:NiceUrlFullPath` call in the RSS creator that was feeding news items. I replaced the `umbraco.library:NiceUrlFullPath` calls with `umbraco.library:NiceUrl` calls and the issue has disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

In the web.config, there is a setting called `umbracoHideTopLevelNodeFromPath`. This causes the behavior you are describing when it is set to false. Do you perhaps have multiple people working on the site and publishing different versions of the web.config that have this setting changed?

When publishing a node with the setting set to `false`, it would add the `/home` part to the URL. Otherwise, it would leave off the `/home`.

Comment: it's set to false and I am the only one updating

Comment: Which umbraco TV video were you following along?

Comment: [building a news section](http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/umbraco-fundamentals/building-a-news-section.aspx)

Comment: Ok, nothing ground breaking there. Looks like it may be a bug, [someone else has ran into it as well](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/22106-umbracoHideTopLevelNodeFromPath-not-working-(randomly)). I have a couple sites running 4.7 that I haven't ran into this though. I would try a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Once the Umbraco application has started, there are several processes that run on a regular basis (e.g. to check for expired content). It is possible to piggy-back on these by creating a custom class that inherits from `umbraco.cms.businesslogic.ApplicationBase`. If you have created one that uses the `Document.AfterPublish` eventhandler then I would check that it is  not causing the issue.

I'm assuming that you haven't written one of these though, so the only other thing I can suggest is checking whether it is an installed package that is causing the issue. Have you installed any Umbraco packages? If so, do they have any automated behaviours, like creating folders etc. If so, this may be causing the issue. The author of a package will usually have a website, codeplex project etc. and they will usually have a issue list or blog.

**Edit**

I've just quickly checked and uBlogsy, one of the plugins you mention exactly this. It has auto moving and sorting of posts. This is described in the release notes. If you are using this tool for creating news pages, then this will be your issue.

Comment: I don't think any of the have automated behaviours. My Packages are uBlogsy, EyeCatch RSS and Media Icons.

Comment: looks like what you are mentioning is in Version1.4 but I am running 1.32

Comment: There have been 3 updates since that version. You should try upgrading first to see if this fixes the issue. You should also check the discussions for bugs raised. Finally, the author has published the source code, which can look through.

Either way, if this is the package being used to create your news articles, and the bug is not occurring elsewhere, then this package is almost certainly causing your issue.

Comment: It's now occurring in sites that I have that don't have the uBlogsy Package installed. I have about 4 sites now, with the same base stuff and this is occuring in all of them. Only one has the uBlogsy stuff in it.